# Inaccuracy of the Difference between two $\chi^2$ Cummulative Distribution Functions

Tags: numerical-integration, probability-or-statistics, distributions

I have an algorithm which needs to calculate the difference of two Gamma distributions evaluated at some large values. I cannot do this over CDFs because they give $1$ if a large value is evaluated. Then the difference of the CDFs is always $0$. Getting a difference of zero is breaking down my code at the optimzation stage. I am able to solve this problem if I use NIntegrate over the PDFs but every iteration needs alot of time and eventually the code is not running due to impracticality or in other words I must wait a day which normally should end in a few minutes at max. Here is my code:

```
m = 1;
ω = {10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10};
γ = {0.1202, 0.1413, 0.1862, 0.2399, 0.3090, 1.0000, 1.5849, 1.9055, 1.9953, 2.5704};

f0[k_,y_] := PDF[ChiSquareDistribution[ω[[k]]], y]
f00[k_, z_] := Gamma[ω[[k]]/2, 0, z/2]/Gamma[ω[[k]]/2]

f1[k_,y_] := \[Piecewise]   ((2(γ[[k]]+1))^(-ω[[k]]/2) E^(-y/(2(γ[[k]]+1))) y^(-1+ω[[k]]/2))/Gamma[ω[[k]]/2]    y>0  0 True
f11[k_, z_] := Gamma[ω[[k]]/2, 0, z/(2 (γ[[k]] + 1))]/Gamma[ω[[k]]/2]

t={120,200};
p0[k_, idx_] := f00[k, t[[idx+1]]] - f00[k, t[[idx]]]
p1[k_, idx_] := f11[k, t[[idx + 1]]] - f11[k, t[[idx]]]
utmp[k_, idx_] := Log[p1[k, idx]/p0[k, idx]]
Subscript[m, 0][k_] := Sum[p0[k, idx]*utmp[k, idx], {idx, 1, m}];
Subscript[s, 0] := Sum[Sum[p0[k, idx]*(utmp[k, idx] - Subscript[m, 0][k])^2, {idx, 1, m}], {k, 1, 10}];
```

Lets evaluate the code:

```
Subscript[s, 0]

Indeterminate
```

If we change

```
t = {20, 25};
```

we get

```
0.517914
```

If I change

```
p0[k_, idx_] := NIntegrate[f0[k, y], {y, t[[idx]], t[[idx + 1]]}]
p1[k_, idx_] := NIntegrate[f1[k, y], {y, t[[idx]], t[[idx + 1]]}]
```

Then for the original case

```
t={120,200};
```

we get

```
3.17318*10^-17
```

But in this case as I said before evaluating Subscript[s, 0] is taking too much time.. Is there anyway to do with without NIntegrate?

here it is[image]

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the issue.  The title is clear about the CDF of a Gamma distribution.  But nowhere in the body is the use of the CDF function on a gamma distribution.  The CDF of the Gamma distribution is exact if you use exact numbers:  `CDF[GammaDistribution[1, 3], 500] - 
  CDF[GammaDistribution[1, 3], 499] ` gets one $\frac{1}{e^{499/3}}-\frac{1}{e^{500/3}}$.  Using `N` on that expression gets one 1.64005*10^-73.

Comment: @JimB f00 is the CDF of the density f0 and f11 is the CDF of the density f1. I am talking about the inaccuary of calculating p0[k_, idx_]  if I use directly the CDF, namely the definition of f00 given in the code above. That is actually CDF of chi squared density not Gamma density as you mentioned but I just wrote it in the title having Gamma everywhere so the CDF of Chi-squared. f1 and f11 are also some kind of chi squared but I dont know exact details.

Comment: `f0` is `f0` and not `CDF`.  Please show why using `CDF[whatever distribution]` doesn't work.  Are you saying that your use of `CDF` in a function you created doesn't work or that the `CDF` function doesn't work as explicitly stated in your title?

Comment: @JimB I didnt say f0 is a CDF, f0 is a density function. f00 is a CDF. If you run my code you will see that p0[k_, idx_] := f00[k, t[[idx+1]]] - f00[k, t[[idx]]] is evaluated to zero. This result is totally wrong. The true result can be obtained by using p0[k_, idx_] := NIntegrate[f0[k, y], {y, t[[idx]], t[[idx + 1]]}]   which is another way of calculating the same thing. I guess you are unhappy with the mismatch between the title and the question?

Comment: Not unhappy, just confused.  There is a lot of code to wade through with no comments inserted AND the title doesn't match the code.  Your code for `f0` might be mathematically equivalent to `CDF` but `CDF` has a whole lot more going for it under the hood.  Have you tried using the `WorkingPrecision` option?

Comment: @jim no I didnt.Where should one use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
m = 1;
ω = {10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10};
```

Convert `γ` to exact values to avoid forcing machine precision calculations

```
γ = {0.1202, 0.1413, 0.1862, 0.2399, 0.3090, 1.0000, 1.5849, 1.9055, 
    1.9953, 2.5704} // Rationalize;

f0[k_, y_] := PDF[ChiSquareDistribution[ω[[k]]], y]
f00[k_, z_] := Gamma[ω[[k]]/2, 0, z/2]/Gamma[ω[[k]]/2]

f1[k_, y_] := 
   Piecewise[{{y^(-1 + ω[[k]]/2)/
             ((2*(γ[[k]] + 1))^(ω[[k]]/2)*
                E^(y/(2*(γ[[k]] + 1))))/
          Gamma[ω[[k]]/2], y > 0}}]

f11[k_, z_] := 
 Gamma[ω[[k]]/2, 0, z/(2 (γ[[k]] + 1))]/Gamma[ω[[k]]/2]

t = {120, 200};
p0[k_, idx_] := f00[k, t[[idx + 1]]] - f00[k, t[[idx]]]
p1[k_, idx_] := f11[k, t[[idx + 1]]] - f11[k, t[[idx]]]
utmp[k_, idx_] := Log[p1[k, idx]/p0[k, idx]]
Subscript[m, 0][k_] := Sum[p0[k, idx]*utmp[k, idx], {idx, 1, m}];
Subscript[s, 0] := 
  Sum[Sum[p0[k, idx]*(utmp[k, idx] - Subscript[m, 0][k])^2, {idx, 1, m}], {k, 
    1, 10}];
```

In evaluating `Subscript[s,0]` use arbitrary-precision rather than machine precision

```
Subscript[s, 0] // N[#, 15] &

(* 3.17318496695314*10^-17 *)
```

**EDIT :** Re your comment

If you enter machine precision numbers you will get machine precision results.

```
Precision[104.93434075028202]

(* MachinePrecision *)

N[f00[9, 200] - f00[9, 104.93434075028202], 100]

(* 0. *)

Precision[%]

(* MachinePrecision *)
```

Use either

```
f00[9, 200] - f00[9, 104.93434075028202`40]

(* 5.5830137827358486462429*10^-18 *)

Precision[%]

(* 22.7469 *)
```

Note that the complexity of the calculation results in a loss of about 17 digits of precision

or

```
f00[9, 200] - f00[9, SetPrecision[104.93434075028202, 40]]

(* 5.5830137827358526192441*10^-18 *)

Precision[%]

(* 22.7469 *)
```

**EDIT 2:** I cannot reproduce the results that you show in your comments. I am using version 12.0.0 on a Mac.

```
f11[1, SetPrecision[525/4, 40]] - f11[1, SetPrecision[225/2, 40]]

(* 4.4711124996345361867775*10^-17 *)

Precision[%]

(* 23.3494 *)

N[f11[1, 525/4] - f11[1, 225/2], 30]

(* 4.47111249963453618677749651064*10^-17 *)

Precision[%]

(* 30. *)
```

Comment: It works but not always. Thats really very very strange.. I received an error message because this  N[f00[9, 200] - f00[9, 104.93434075028202`], 100]  was evaluated to zero although NIntegrate[f0[9, y], {y, 104.93434075028202`, 200}] gives me 5.58301*10^-18

Comment: do you have any idea what is special with this number 104.93434075028202? if I replace this number with 105 again I get something which is small but non-zero so works fine but not for this special number..

Comment: Bob, thank you very much for the edit. You are right but It seems that it is out of my control because of my lack of mathematica knowledge. I am using NMaximize and inside this, there is f00[...]-f00[x] and here, $x$ is the variable over which NMaximize is maximizing. How can I tell NMaximize to stop using machine precision but rather to use the precision of my interest? else it finds at some point of maximization some indeterminate results and quits the optimization..

Comment: I did like this NMaximize[{r[k, idx, \[Lambda]], 0 <= \[Lambda] <= 149.9}, \[Lambda], 
 WorkingPrecision -> 30] and i still have the same problem but it says "The precision of the argument function (0<=\[Lambda]<=149.9) is less \
than WorkingPrecision (30)." and NMaximize::nnum: The function value Indeterminate is not a number at {\[Lambda]} = {0.170947490850151928576394766424}.

Comment: 0`30 <= \[Lambda] <= 149.9`30  after this I dont get this one "The precision of the argument function (0<=[Lambda]<=149.9) is less \ than WorkingPrecision (30)." but I still get The function value Indeterminate is not a number at {[Lambda]} = {0.170947490850151928576394766424}

Comment: yes. i was also thinking about it. Thanks for your replies...

Comment: I think the problem is not a new one. Right now It is not about NMaximize but about the question above. Just consider this one f11[1, SetPrecision[525/4, 40]] - f11[1, SetPrecision[225/2, 40]] this gives 0 and I do your another suggestion N[f11[1, 525/4] - f11[1, 225/2], 30] and I still get 0 as the result although NIntegrate[f1[1, y], {y, 225/2, 525/4}] gives me 4.47111*10^-17..

Comment: Thats really weird. I have windows and I tried with versions 9,10 and 11 all failed to give me the correct results as you posted. I always got "0"  for both options in your second edit. Maybe I could ask JimB to try and see if he also has the same problem as I do.

Comment: I downloaded and setup mathematica 12.0.0.0 on my windows machine. Yet, I cannot reproduce the results you posted. I still get 0. Thats totally weird.

Comment: Copy and paste the code from above to see what you get.

Comment: I did and I got exactly the same result as you did.. But If I use my own code I still get 0. I put a screenshot from my code and how I got zero into the question. please let me know if you have any comment about it..

Comment: I noticed that the condition was missing from my Piecewise. After adding it, there were no changes. I cannot detect any problems with your code from an image. Convert your cells to `Raw InputForm` and copy and paste the code into your question, then format as a code block.

Answer (score 1):

***Edit:***  I've changed this from an extended comment to an answer.

The title concerns estimating the difference between two $\chi^2$ distribution functions.  The text has the appearance of not directly addressing that question because of the large amount of code that doesn't explicitly mention a distribution function (at least in my opinion).

A brute force approach is to create a function that calculates the difference explicitly:

```
f[n_?IntegerQ, z1_?NumericQ, z2_?NumericQ, nDigits_: 50] := 
 N[CDF[ChiSquareDistribution[n], Rationalize[z2]] - 
   CDF[ChiSquareDistribution[n], Rationalize[z1]], nDigits]
```

For an example:

```
f[10, 199, 200]
(* 9.9470513771808598331974744855157686475664682149287*10^-38 *)
```

However, this direct approach fails for more extreme values of $z_1$ and $z_2$.  Note that the difference in the CDF functions is a function of the incomplete gamma function:

```
PiecewiseExpand[
   CDF[ChiSquareDistribution[n], z2] - CDF[ChiSquareDistribution[n], z1],
   Assumptions -> {z1 > 0, z2 > 0}] // FunctionExpand // FullSimplify


(* (Gamma[n/2, z1/2] - Gamma[n/2, z2/2])/Gamma[n/2] *)
```

This is the same as using

```
Gamma[n/2, z1/2, z2/2]/Gamma[n/2]
```

So a more stable function for the difference in two $\chi^2$ distribution functions (with the same number of degrees of freedom) is

```
g[n_?IntegerQ, z1_?NumericQ, z2_?NumericQ, nDigits_: 50] := 
 N[Gamma[n/2, Rationalize[z1/2], Rationalize[z2/2]]/Gamma[n/2], nDigits]
g[10, 199999, 200000]

(* 9.6305672408760073406090960801307527696848945201455*10^-43412 *)
```

Comment: Hello Jim. Would you mind trying the code f11[1, SetPrecision[525/4, 40]] - f11[1, SetPrecision[225/2, 40]] at your mathematica and let me know if it gives zero or something like 10^-17? The issue is about the answer posted by Bob.

Comment: I get 4.4711124996345361867775*10^-17 on Windows 10, *Mathematica* 12.0.

Comment: It would still be good to make an explicit match with your title and your code.  Those that might be most helpful to you don't need to know the form of a chisquare cumulative distribution function.  In other words, make an minimal working example.  I still don't see that you've done that.  You essentially have "CDF" in your title but the code only has "PDF".

Comment: Jim, thank you very much for the answer. I also got the same result with copy paste but with my own code I still get 0 and both are actually the same.. anyways..  ?Numeric is a very good idea..